# How to crosstab a table with many entries in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

My table looks like this (with 250 countries listed under "id_country" and 50 years under "year"):

```
    id_country  year    value
        4       2000      5
        4       2001      6
        4       2002      4
        4       2003      8
        8       2000      7
        8       2001      6
        8       2002      9
        8       2003      3
        12      2000      6
        12      2001      4
        12      2002      7
        12      2003      5
```

And I'd like to convert this via a query into this

```
          4    8    12    16   ...
  2000    5    7    
  2001    6
  2003    4
  2004    8
   ...
```

I've done something similar with PHP via loops, but that was a bit strange. I wonder if there is a more direct and smooth, Postgres-SQL-way of doing this. Perhaps not possible without a Postgres function? I am unfortunately not such an expert in it.

Comment: Crosstabs are inherently complex in SQL because this is not how SQL works. The number of columns of a query must be know **before** the query is executed. So the best way to do crosstabs is in the application layer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use crosstab function as below;

```
CREATE TABLE "test1"
(
  id_country integer NOT NULL,
  year text NOT NULL,
  value integer
)

INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (4,'2000', 5);
INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (4,'2001', 6);
INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (4,'2002', 4);
INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (4,'2003', 8);
INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (8,'2000', 7);
INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (8,'2001', 6);
INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (8,'2002', 9);
INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (8,'2003', 3);
INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (12,'2000', 6);
INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (12,'2001', 4);
INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (12,'2002', 7);
INSERT INTO test1 (id_country,year,value) VALUES (12,'2003', 5);


SELECT *
FROM crosstab(
  'select year, id_country, value
   from test1
   order by 1,2')
AS ct(year text, "4" int, "8" int, "12" int);
```

if you get as ERROR: function crosstab(unknown), you should run this;

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

[image]